# Trying to extract a version number from a line in a HTML doc using Unix on Mac

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, unix, sh

I'm trying to extract the current stable version number of Chrome from Google's website https://cloud.google.com/chrome-enterprise/browser/download/ to add to a script that will check the current stable build and update if it doesn't match. I've really fallen at the first hurdle here.

I'm running a script using #!/bin/sh on Mac. The command I am using is:

```
currentVersion="$(curl https://cloud.google.com/chrome-enterprise/browser/download/ | grep "Chrome DMG for OS X")"
```

This isolates the line where the info is shown in the dev tools on chrome:

```
<p class="cloud-browser__title-bold">
    Chrome DMG for OS X
    <br>
    <span class="cloud-browser-downloads__dl-row-version">
        v 70.0.3538.110
    </span>
</p>
```

But when I'm pulling it the only bit I want 'v 70.0.3538.110' doesn't show. Using grep on any on the version string doesn't do anything at all. I just don't understand what is happening. I think maybe it's pulling the number from elsewhere and populating the page but I can't see any evidence of this (in the accessibility view in chrome dev tools it shows it as text).

PLEH!!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

There is an option and is the one to curl the changelog page of Google Chorme web browser that is [this](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/search/label/Stable%20updates) if you want stable updates and [this one](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/) if you want all the versions even dev.
The command is:

```sh
curl https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/search/label/Stable%20updates | grep "Mac" | tr -d "<>-:;/,&\"=#[a-z][A-Z]" | head -1 | sed -e "s/666666//g;s/ . //g;s/ //g"
```

The output is

```sh
70.0.3538.110
```

Without any space and is a string ready to be used

## Google's fault: it uses static technology to update webpages

If you want to get the version from `cloud.google.com/chrome-enterprise/browser/download/` you will simply ending up without a result.

## Alternative that work as now

Try using curl on a different site, going around that google uses a static tool to change the version number inside the web page.
something like this should work, as long as WhatIsMyBrowser don't close the site itself

```sh
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/chrome | grep -A 1 "MacOS" | tr -d "<[a-z][A-Z]>/"
```

## To know what version you have installed

If you want to estract the version you have currently installed, simply type
 `google-chrome --version`
 and if you want to estract simply the version to compute with bash you have to type
 `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version   | grep -iE "[0-9.]{10,20}"`
playing a bit with regular expression. 
This works from the terminal. 
There is also a gui version directly from chrome, simply go yo the url `chrome://version` or`about:` gives you a site with all the information about chrome

Comment: Sorry @Leonardo Silvagni, I'm trying to gather what the current available version from google is. I've edited my question as it was a little ambiguous.

Comment: @S.Smoonery Ah ok so when you grep it it does not show up? Let me work it out

Comment: indeed @Leonardo Silvagni You can copy it directly from the dev tools into a text file but curl just doesn't lift it :(

Comment: @S.Smoonery Course this is not a definitive way to go, but it is the **simplest** solution I thought about. I really don't know wether google provides another web page where stores the version number of chrome, maybe try with the changelog, wait I'll put in the answer

Comment: @S.Smoonery Was it helpful, did you manage to write your script?

Comment: Hi @Leonardo Silagni. My apologies I didn't respond yesterday. Yes, it was very helpful and allowed me to implement a solution. I'm going to need to keep and eye out on the website site as I need a static source of the version no. so might need to get onto Google to see how I can also get that number. Thanks for your help.